# Using one stock price as a predictor for another stock price

Tags: time-series, correlation, finance, stationarity, decomposition

I have two stock prices with a strong trend which are non-stationary.

I want to calculate the correlation between one stock say $x$ and another stock say $y$, but lagged 7 days back. Why should I have to decompose it? 
Can I just use the $x$ stock as an indicator of where the price of $y$ stock will be in 7 days?

Comment: I don't see why not. Just run a regression where stock X is the independent variable and stock Y (lagged 7 days) is the predictor.

Comment: If both series are non-stationary your results are prone to be spurious, they're actually gonna reflect the relation between the deterministic/stochastic trend than the actual the data. It's real common sense in literature to use return instead of spot price.

Comment: @lucasfariaslf, *they're actually gonna reflect the relation between the deterministic/stochastic trend than the actual the data*? I would disagree. The actual data is dominated by these trends, that is, the data basically **is** the trends themselves. So the real problem here is that we are not interested in the actual data but rather its increments (returns).

Comment: But if I want to buy if they correlated and lagged let's say one week. If I observe the price to drop for stock x then I should short stock y lets say on day 6. Why Do I need returns for that? Since I don't use any beta or diversification why do I need to know returns?

Comment: @RichardHardy agreed, shouldn't have said *data*, did so considering that whichever existing non-stationary information doesn't help us understand the relationship between the stocks.

Comment: Your first paragraph is not comprehensible. Also the question requires a self study tag.